# Serializing Struct of vectors of vector

Tags: c++, serialization, file-io

I`m in a bit complicated situation here.
I want to save a struct of vectors to a file and read it after some time.
But the problem is with the reading. I dont know how i can fill al vectors into structure from the saved file.

```
 struct TDNATable{


        std::vector<String>GenomOne;
        std::vector<String>GenomeL;
        std::vector<String>GenomeER;
        std::vector<String>GenomeRET;
        std::vector<String>GenomeSEL;

    };

    std::vector<TDNATable> DnaTbl;



//PSEUDO CODE:
    //For example simple writing could be
    ofstream file("C:\\Users\\User11\\Desktop\\SNF_TBL.INI", ios::binary);
    file.write((char*)&DnaTbl, sizeof(DnaTbl));

//Problem comes with reading 
 // impl
    ifstream file("C:\\Users\\User11\\Desktop\\SNF_TBL.INI",
        std::ifstream::binary);

    // get pointer to associated buffer object
    std::filebuf* pbuf = file.rdbuf();

    // get file size using buffer's members
    std::size_t size = pbuf->pubseekoff(0, file.end, file.in);
    pbuf->pubseekpos(0, file.in);

    // allocate memory to contain file data
    char* buffer = new char[size];

    // get file data
    pbuf->sgetn(buffer, size);

    file.close();


for (int i = 0; i < SnfTbl.size(); i++) {

//Back inserter can be used only with 1D vector        
std::copy(buffer, buffer +sizeof(buffer),
            std::back_inserter(SnfTbl[i].GenomeL);

        std::copy(buffer, buffer +sizeof(buffer),
            std::back_inserter(SnfTbl[i].GenomeER));



    }

    RefreshDFSGrid();


    delete[]buffer;
    file.close();
```

I tried with boost/serialize but without sucsess.

Do you have any idea how can i save/load this ds in a elegant way?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost could be an overkill for easy tasks. In my own code, I solved that problem with sorts of stream class. I did it that way:

1. Declare abstract base class with `virtual Read(buffer, byteCount) = 0` and `virtual Write(buffer, byteCount) = 0`. In illustration below, `IArchiveI` and `IArchiveO` are such base classes.
2. For builtin types, provide `operator <<` and `operator >>` that simply calls Read() and Write() as appropriate.
3. For library types such as vector / string / ..., provide non-member template operators built on base type operators (eg you no longer call raw Read / Write).

For instance, there's how I handle a vector:

```
template <class T>
IArchiveO& operator << (IArchiveO& a_Stream, const std::vector<T>& a_Vector)
{
    a_Stream << a_Vector.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a_Vector.size(); i++)
    {
        a_Stream << a_Vector[i];
    }

    return a_Stream;
}

template <class T>
IArchiveI& operator >> (IArchiveI& a_Stream, std::vector<T>& a_Vector)
{
    a_Vector.clear();

    size_t contSize = 0;
    a_Stream >> contSize;

    a_Vector.resize(contSize);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contSize; i++)
    {
        a_Stream >> a_Vector[i];
    }

    return a_Stream;
}
```

For non-library types of your own, provide operators the same way.
For instance, here's how your code would look like:

```
IArchiveI& operator >> (IArchiveI& a_Stream, TDNATable& a_Value)
{
    a_Stream >> a_Value.GenomOne;
    a_Stream >> a_Value.GenomeL;
    a_Stream >> a_Value.GenomeER;
    a_Stream >> a_Value.GenomeRET;
    a_Stream >> a_Value.GenomeSEL;
    return a_Stream;
}
```

4. Inherit from base classes and make classes that provide storage, for instance, reading/writing to file. You will only need to overload `virtual Read(buffer, byteCount)` and `virtual Write(buffer, byteCount)`.
5. Finally, you construct an instance of storage class and serialize your entire array in one go (in this code, CFileArchiveO is inherited from IArchiveO, overloading Write()):
   `CFileArchiveO ar(...);
   ar << DnaTbl;`

The trick is, when compiler has operators for each type, it **automatically** builds code for whatever nesting you have, even if it's a `vector<vector<vector<string>>>`

Comment: IArchiveI and IArchiveO are not standard C++ classes. Should this example code be modified to use standard C++ types?

Comment: These are base classes mentioned in point 1. I updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` allocates memory when inserting data.

So

`file.write((char*)&DnaTbl, sizeof(DnaTbl));`

only saves the "*metadata*" of `std::vector<TDnaTbl>` and leaves out the data you inserted, which is stored somewhere else in memory. You would have to iterate over the vector and save the element count and the element-data manually.